# Qt error: undefined reference to `srcml_create_archive'

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I'm starting in C++ with [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) and I want to add a third part library, but I've got some errors:

```
#include <srcml.h>

int main()
{
    srcml_archive* srcml_arch = srcml_create_archive();
    srcml_read_open_filename(srcml_arch,"suma.c.xml");

    srcml_unit* unit = srcml_read_unit(srcml_arch);

    srcml_unparse_unit_filename(unit,"suma.c");
    srcml_free_unit(unit);

    srcml_close_archive(srcml_arch);
    srcml_free_archive(srcml_arch);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
/h...cML/main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `srcml_create_archive'
```

I wonder, why?

Comment: Linker error, do you link with the srcml.lib?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: What buildsystem are you using? Is it qmake, cmake, autotools or something else? Either way, can you show the buildsystem file? In general, your linkage rule does not seem to suffix. How exactly is the library called? Please provide answers to all of these questions in order to be able to give the proper answer.

Comment: If you share the details asked for, I will try to reopen and answer it. Otherwise, it is impossible to answer it in a non-duplicate manner.

Answer (score 0):

In your .`pro`, you have to **set the include path** where is located `srcml.h` and **link the library**:

#### .pro

```
# Path where srcml.h is
INCLUDEPATH += "path/to/library/include"

# Link your library
LIBS += -L"path/to/library/lib" -l[library_name]
```

I don't know the name of the library, replace `[library_name]` with the library name.

Comment: :~$ sudo sbin ldconfig -v
this is the solution that solved my problem, thanks for everything.